# c# xml comment change in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-comments

I am having trouble with an xml comment on a web api controller method.  I have a class with several properties as a parameter on this method.  When I want to add a description to the properties within that class on the method it builds it with an extra extension, and swagger cannot interpret the documentation for its UI. This worked just fine in visual studio 2013 but in 2015 it changes the output to the xml documentation file.

My methods xml Comments:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get alerts for your Id.  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Id"></param>
    /// <param name="alertRequest"></param>
    /// <param name="alertRequest.category">Accepted Values: examples of accepted values are...</param>
```

My Method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOpenAlerts(Guid Id, [FromUri] AlertRequest alertRequest){}
```

XML output when compiling in Visual Studio 2013:

```
name="Api.Controllers.AlertController.GetOpenAlerts(System.Guid,Api.Domain.Models.AlertRequest)">
        <summary>
        Get alerts for your Id.  
        </summary>
        <param name="Id"></param>
        <param name="alertRequest"></param>
        <param name="alertRequest.category">Accepted Values: examples of accepted values are ...</param>
        <returns></returns>``
```

Output in Visual Studio 2015:

```
<member name="Api.Controllers.AlertController.GetOpenAlerts(System.Guid,Api.Domain.Models.AlertRequest)">
        <summary>
        Get alerts for your Id. 
        </summary>
        <param name="Id"></param>
        ***<param name="alertRequest.category.category"***>Accepted Values: examples of accepted values are...</param>
        <returns></returns>
```

Is there a setting I need to change for xml comments in visual studio 2015?  Why does it automatically add the extra extension and duplicate the property?

Comment: Your XML comments are invalid to begin with. `alertRequest` is a parameter, `alertRequest.category` is not. You're just lucky this happened to work in VS 2013. If you want to add usage notes that further restrict an argument beyond type, use a `<remarks>` section.

Comment: I agree - I can (should) add a <summary> on the property itself inside the class and they will show up in swagger.  I just thought visual studio was robbing me of a cool shortcut here in its latest release. If you want to post it as an answer I can accept...

Comment: @JeroenMostert VS 2015 uses the Roslyn based csc.exe, and it seems to be stricter on checking XML comments.